# How to change object key value number to string value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am working on a project; the object has a dynamic key and a dynamic value. I will find which number the keys are holding, and change the number to string value, assuming the object list is too big to check each individually- more than 30 key values

```
const obj =  {
    one: 'jkej',
    two: 123,
    three: 'abc'
  }
```

Required output is

```
const obj =  {
    one: 'jkej',
    two: '123',
    three: 'abc'
  }
```

I want to change the what are the keys holding, and change the number value to string.

Comment: Loop them, convert everything to a string?

Comment: *"I want to change..."*: what is holding you back to do so? Any research into (1) how to loop over entries in an object (2) how to give a key a new value (3) how to convert a string to a number? Which is the part that isn't working for you?

Comment: @Bergi Yes all the values will be string

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the keys of the object and convert the values to string

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
  obj[k] = obj[k].toString()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const obj = {
  one: 'jkej',
  two: 123,
  three: 'abc'
}

const convertToString = (object) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object)
    .map(([k, v]) => [k, v + ''])
  )


console.log(convertToString(obj))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through the object and cast everything into a string using
toString():

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myObject)) {
    value = value.toString()
}
```